# Beginner level questions

Tags: permissions

I apologize if I'm not asking in the correct area. I had a few questions that I can't seem to find answers for. If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

1.) If a manager had access to employee files, but couldn't see the files of other managers, would that be considered a permission set or a rule determined by a profile? Or is that how a generic role hierarchy would work? Or org default?

2.) If a company wanted to test a new license out, would they use a sandbox or developer org? I wasn't sure if a new license would warrant a full org or not?

3.) When an account is deleted because the company went out of business, what also gets deleted along with it? I've found mixed answers. Is it leads, opportunities, related information, or contacts?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Despite you getting an answer to the three unrelated questions you have posed here, could you please in future ask each question separately and ensure the summary states the question itself? In addition we typically like to see evidence of research and/or some attempt to resolve your issue in the body of your question. It is uncommon to get answers to questions that show no effort. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that! I'll make sure my future questions follow this format!

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Sharing

At a fundamental level, this would be based on a combination of factors. For this to happen, the Organization Wide Defaults would be set to Private, the manager would not have a System Administrator profile (or any other View All Data permission), based on the Role Hierarchy configuration, and no applicable Sharing Rules or Territory Sharing Rules. Security is Salesforce is, to put it mildly, a complicated affair. There are many ways to give a user access to a record, and in order to not have that happen, a large number of things must not be set.

## 2. Testing

Fundamentally, Sandboxes are typically used to test out new features. This is due to the fact that a Sandbox represents a copy of your own org, while a Developer Edition or Scratch Org starts off as a generic template with nothing in it. If you want to quickly be able to see a new feature as it applies to your org, use a Sandbox. If you want to test out the feature generically, just to see what it does, you can use any type of org, though I find that Scratch Orgs are bit nicer, as you can turn on most feature licenses without contacting Support, though with the tradeoff that you don't necessarily get to see what a feature would look like in *your* org.

## 3. Cascade Deletion

Accounts are a very large object that contain a lot of information. Deleting an Account deletes almost everything related to that Account, including, Contacts, Contracts, Opportunities, Quotes, Orders, all Activity records (Task and Event) related to any child object also deleted, all Notes and Attachments related to the Account or any child object affected, Product Line Items, Account, Contact, and Case Team Members, Case Comments, Emails, custom objects configured with cascade deletion, and other items. There are a few system validations that will prevent deletion of the Account, such as having a Case associated to it; in those cases, you'll be required to manually delete the child records before deleting the Account.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping! These were test questions on a practice exam and they didn't provide the answers so I felt so lost. I knew the the differences between developer orgs was mostly the size options and how often you can refresh them but I don't think trailhead mentioned licenses at all so I had no idea if you needed the full org or not. Thank you again! Salesforce is a bit overwhelming but I hope to get better!